# Explicit getter in Scala

Tags: scala, getter

```
class Car(val miles:Int,val year:Int)

val myCar = new Car(100,2016);
println(myCar.miles)
```

In this example `myCar.miles` gives me the value of miles. But I want to define explicit getters to do something with the miles property of myCar. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a method:

```
class Car(mi: Int, val year: Int) {
  def miles = 2 * mi
}

val myCar = new Car(100, 2016)
println(myCar.miles)   // prints 200
```

Or, since the value is immutable, define a `val` so that the computation is done only once (instead of every time you call the method):

```
class Car(mi: Int, val year: Int) {
  val miles = 2 * mi
}
```

Comment: As I understand it not required to do an override for mi val? But can this be done at all ?

Comment: `mi` is just a constructor argument, by not putting `val` in front of it, you don't get the automatically provided getter and setter.

Comment: I mean that this will not be valid in terms of pure FP, but if this allowed in Scala?? as I see its not.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Why is this "not valid in terms of pure FP"? And what exactly do you think is or is not allowed in Scala? Do you understand exactly how the code in my answer works, or is there something you don't understand?

Comment: I do understand how code works. My questions is around override.But I have feeling its doesn't make any sense at all do have an option override values in the constructor and expose them as public properties etc. Feel free to ignore this discussion.